# How to disable a particular module for logging

Tags: python, logging, paramiko

I have `logging` set up at the `INFO` level. However, I want to remove all logs from a particular module, regardless of level:

```
[:pid:8229 2021-06-14 19:32:06,827] - INFO paramiko.transport:_log:L1819: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.6p1)
[:pid:8229 2021-06-14 19:32:06,846] - INFO paramiko.transport:_log:L1819: Authentication (publickey) successful!
```

How would I do the equivalent of the following?

```
logger = logging.getLogger(self.script_name)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.disableLogger(paramiko) # pseudocode
```

I suppose one option is doing something like:

```
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: You could do something like `logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL+1)`. As you have it now, log messages would still propagate upward for messages of `ERROR` and `CRITICAL` severity.

Comment: @Stephen thanks, that's a good suggestion. That whole 'logging from another module' gets so annoying. Is there a way to just wipe out all other modules at the start (in other words, to include them if I want them rather than exclude them if I don't) ?

Comment: There are a few things you could do, but probably the easiest to implement is to just not add any handler to the root logger and then only add a handler (`StreamHandler`, `RotatingFileHandler`, etc.) for the logger instance that you create.

Comment: @Stephen good points. Want to put those two together into an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logging` module has no concept of module-level loggers, as every logger is just established in a hierarchy based on name. `paramiko.transport` will always exist as a child logger of the `paramiko` logger by name, not by any module association. Because of this, there isn't really a good way to disable logging by module itself, but you can *effectively* disable logging for that logger and all child loggers by doing something like `logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL+1)`, since every log message should propagate with a logging level that will be lower than this value, it will cause any log message to drop out before reaching a handler attached to the root logger.

Another question was raised about disabling all logging and then selectively enabling logging where needed. To achieve something like this, the quickest method would be to exclude the addition of any handlers to the root logger, and then add handlers in a "bottom-up" fashion. The reason you would want to do this is because if you end up attaching a handler to a logger that is the child of a logger that the handler has already been attached to, you will get duplicate logging messages, which is definitely of note.